How to Configure freeRADIUS to Accept Only Specific MAC Address and Username?
I have freeRADIUS on my openwrt. I need it to authenticate via mac address. how do i do it?
when I try, all devices connect successfully, I only need to connect the device with address 84:A9:38:9C:8E:24.
how to fix it?????????
